# How to fix Jquery ui sortable for Windows Touch devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable

I try to sort an accordion with the Jquery UI sortable function. It works fine with Android Phones and on IPad. It also works with the mouse on desktop. 
When I try it on Windows 10 Touch devices it fails in all browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Edge, Opera).

I am currently using jquery-3.4.1 (nessesary for boostrap etc.),  JQuery UI v1.12.1 and jQuery UI Touch Punch 0.2.3.

I tryed using JQuery Mobile, but then it did not work for all devices.

---

```
$(function () {
$("#accordion")
    .collapse()
    .sortable({
        delay: 200,
        opacity: 0.5,
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        update: function (event, ui) {
            var order = "";
            var divs = $("#accordion").children("div");
            divs.each(function () {
                var x = $(this).attr("data-customid");
                order = order.concat(x + ";");
            });
            var token = getCookie("jwtToken");
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.example.net/api/project/update/' + order,
                type: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    Authorization: "Bearer " + token
                },
                success: function (msg) {
                    var arrayk = msg.split(";");

                    arrayk.forEach(function (e) {
                        console.log(e);
                        if (e != "") {

                            var arrayX = e.split(":");
                            var projectId = arrayX[0];
                            var status = arrayX[1];
                            console.log(status);
                            console.log(projectId);

                        }
                    });

                    $("#success-alert").fadeTo(2500, 500).slideUp(500, function () {
                        $("#success-alert").slideUp(500);
                    });
                }
            });
        },
        connectWith: "#dropCard",
        axis: "y"
    });


$("#dropCard")
    .sortable({
        connectWith: "#accordion"
    });
});
```

Comment: This is possibly what you are looking for: https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch

Comment: I am using this script, but it seems no longer supportet by firefox and all new browsers versions for windows. In firefox 53 it is still working but in 67/68 it is not working.